# Dask - Quickest way to get row length of each partition in a Dask dataframe

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed, fastparquet

I'd like to get the length of each partition in a number of dataframes.  I'm presently getting each partition and then getting the size of the index for each partition.  This is very, very slow.  Is there a better way?

Here's a simplified snippet of my code:

```
   temp_dd = dd.read_parquet(read_str, gather_statistics=False)
   temp_dd = dask_client.scatter(temp_dd, broadcast=True)
   dask_wait([temp_dd])
   temp_dd = dask_client.gather(temp_dd)

   while row_batch <= max_row:
       row_batch_dd = temp_dd.get_partition(row_batch)
       row_batch_dd = row_batch_dd.dropna()    
       row_batch_dd_len = row_batch_dd.index.size  # <-- this is the current way I'm determining the length
       row_batch = row_batch + 1
```

I note that, while I am reading a parquet, I can't simply use the parquet info (which is very fast) because, after reading, I do some partition-by-partition processing and then drop the NaNs.  It's the post-processed length per partition that I'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = dd.read_parquet(fn, gather_statistics=False)
df = df.dropna()
df.map_partitions(len).compute()
```

Comment: explanation please?

Comment: 1. Read in parquet file into variable `df`.
2. drop missing values from data frame, `df`.
3. For each `df` partition, calculate the the `len` (this is what `map_partitions` is doing). And return the calcualted value to the user (this is what `compute` is doing). Untill `compute` is called, everthing is "lazy" so you don't get any work done.

This works because in normal pandas `len(df)` will give you the number of rows in a dataframe. When you use `map_partitions` a dataframe gets passed into the function.